# Cant send email with correct characters with PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a e-mail with the PHPmailer class, but the html i send, is empty, or the characters are unconfigured, and without accents.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true);
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include "config.php";

$nome = trim($_POST['nome']);
$email  = trim($_POST['Imail']);
$usuario = trim($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = trim($_POST['senha']);
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
  $mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);
  $mail->SetFrom('editora@conectfarma.net', 'Conectfarma');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('editora@conectfarma.net', 'Conectarma');
  $subject = 'Guia Rápido de Interações Medicamentosas';
  $sendsubject= "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
  $mail->Subject = $sendsubject;
 $mensagem  = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Bem vindo ao Guia Rápido de Interações Medicamentosas em Neurologia e Psiquiatria
Seu Login e Senha para acesso ao aplicativo são:\n
Login:"  .$nome. "\n, Senha : " .$senha.
"\nAtenciosamente,
Conectfarma Publicações Científicas
</body>
</html>";

  $mail->Body = $mensagem;
  //$mail->CreateBody($mensagem);
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->Send();
  //$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
  echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
<title>Confirmação</title>
</head>
<body>
Não vai maçã.
</body>
</html>
";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I jumped the SMTP configuration because its working properly.

Comment: Ensure that your code is UTF8, uncomment `$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";`. Don't write code in your native language.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk just commented that, but still, the email that im receiving is "NÃ£o vai maÃ§Ã£." and sorry about the native language.

Comment: Are you really, really sure, that your files are UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Uncommenting that line is not enough - You also have to move it BEFORE the `$mail->Send();` line...idealy right after `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Double check Your PHP code is also in UTF-8 encoding.

Uncomment the line `//$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";` and move it idealy right after the `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`, so the code would look like:

```php
// ...
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
// ...
```

In Your code it is called after the `$mail->Send();` thus the charset setting did not take in count...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, right after the "new PHPMailer(true);".
I had the same problem with:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->setLanguage('fr', 'inc'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'PHPMailer'…);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

and changing to:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
try {
    $mail->setLanguage('fr', 'inc'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'PHPMailer'…);
```

solved the accents problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solution might also be of help:

I added:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Then to the strings which I had accented letters in I used **htmlentities** with the exception of html tags. So something like this:

```
'<p><?php echo htmlentities("För servicerapport") ?></p>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help somebody, as it helped me.

```
<?php $this->phpmailer->Subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=\r\n"; ?>
```