# PHP form - How to sent email that contain UTF-8 character

Tags: php, forms, email, utf-8, phpmailer

I am continuing to developing a web from previous developer that allow user to sent query form. Some of the user is Chinese therefore they tend to use Chinese character when they fill the form. When they sent the form,the email I receive will show this

```
å ‰éš†å ¡/é›ªå…°èŽªå·ž
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem?
Here is the code

query_process.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once "includes/phpmailer.php";


$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);


$subject = "[Website] Contact Form";
$body = "<p>Name: $name</p>
         <p>Email: $email</p>
         <p>Subject: $subject</p>
         <p>Message : $message</p>
        ";
        //$cf_mail_replyto
if(sendPHPMail('___', '___', '___', $subject, $body))
    echo "success";
else
    echo "fail";
?>
```

query_from.php:

```
...
function submitForm()
{
    if($("#name").val() == "")
        alert("Sorry, please fill in your name.");
        else
            if($("#email").val() == "")
        alert("Sorry, please fill in your email.");
        else
            if($("#subject").val() == "")
        alert("Sorry, please fill in your subject.");
        else
            if($("#message").val() == "")
        alert("Sorry, please fill in your message.");
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "query_process.php",
            data: $("#enquiry").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "success"){
                    alert("Your enquiry has been sent successfully.");
                window.location.reload();
                }
                else{
                    //console.log(data);
                    //alert(data);
                alert("There's problem sending your enquiry. Please try again later.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
...
</script>
//my form
...
```

Comment: what version of phpmailer are you using ... seems like an old one.

Comment: I am not sure which version is that because I am continuing previous developer work at the place where I do my internship. Is there anyway to solve it? Does the version affect?

Answer (score 1):

1. don't use the mysql extension any more
2. why on earth are you using mysql_real_escape_string in an email context
3. what email viewer are you using
4. what exactly is in the `sendPHPMail` function? Is that a wrapper for the `phpmailer` class? Check [Cant send email with correct characters with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956663/cant-send-email-with-correct-characters-with-phpmailer) on how to send UTF-8 mail with `phpmailer`.
5. Does the HTML page containing the form have the appropriate UTF-8 encoding?